# Self referential structs in c

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to move some code that was compiling fine as C++ in VS2010 to c (gcc c99) and I'm getting compilation errors. It's a little different than the other self-referential struct questions, because I have 2 user defined types, each of which contains pointers to one another. It seems my forward declartions aren't enough.

```
struct potato; //forward declare both types
struct tomato;

struct potato
{
    potato* pPotato; //error: unknown type name ‘potato’
    tomato* pTomato;

};

struct tomato
{
    potato* pPotato;
    tomato* pTomato;
};
```

Why does this not work in gcc 99? Why is it ok as C++ code? How should I modify this to get the same behavior as c99?

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: edited to show line of the error

Answer (score 9):

Alternatively, `typedef` them both

```
typedef struct potato potato; //forward declare both types
typedef struct tomato tomato;

struct potato
{
    potato* pPotato;
    tomato* pTomato;

};

struct tomato
{
    potato* pPotato;
    tomato* pTomato;
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Self-referential types are valid in C, but in C `struct`s live in a different namespace to variables/constants and must be prefixed with `struct` when their name is used.

Also, avoid Hungarian Notation, in your case the `p` prefix.

Try this:

```
struct potato; //forward declare both types
struct tomato;

struct potato
{
    struct potato* potato;
    struct tomato* tomato;

};

struct tomato
{
    struct potato* potato;
    struct tomato* tomato;
};
```

The traditional way of avoiding having to constantly type `struct foo` was to use a `typedef`:

```
typedef struct potato potato;
```

The definition of `struct potato` can be used anonymously and inline:

```
typedef struct { ... } potato;
```

I have made a personal observation that use of `typedef struct` seems to be in decline and using the "longhand" form of always specifying `struct` when used is back in vogue.

Comment: Is hungarian notation frowned upon nowadays? Why do you recommend avoiding it?

Comment: @user2864293 because it hinders readability and doesn't confer any useful information. Your compiler and IDE know what the types are already so you can get even more information just by hovering your mouse cursor over the name.

Comment: @user2864293 and it also hinders maintainability: if you're using C++ and have a raw pointer and decide to change it to a smart-pointer then you would have to rename your `p` and `ptr` prefixes everywhere they were used.

Comment: I think it should work without the forward declarations.

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
struct potato
{
    struct potato* pPotato;
    struct tomato* pTomato;

};
```

Plain C doesn't automatically typedef structures.

Personally, I like automatic typedefing (I use a short posfix to convey that a typedef is a struct) so I've been kind of simulating it with a macro:

```
#define Struct(Nam,...) typedef struct Nam Nam; struct Nam __VA_ARGS__

Struct(tomato,);
Struct(potato,);

Struct( potato, {
    potato* pPotato; //error: unknown type name ‘potato’
    tomato* pTomato;

});

Struct(tomato, {
    potato* pPotato;
    tomato* pTomato;
});

tomato tom;
potato pot;
```

Comment: What if I wanted to also include a typedef, so I dont have to modify the rest of the code that has lots of potatoes and tomatoes without "struct" in front them?

Comment: @user2864293 I personally use a macro that prepends the typedef to each struct definition. I've added it to the answer.

Comment: This relies on a gcc extension (allowing no arguments to match `, ...`)

Comment: @M.M Added commas to the forward declarations. (I've actually never used this to forward declare before.  I simply use it for definitions to have a typedef auto-prepended).